# issue when copy between workbooks vba when large number of line

Tags: vba, excel

My code is working the probleme is that when I  try to copy large number of lines my excel get closed ( crash). Any help please.

```
Sub test()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim Wb1 As Workbook, Wb2 As Workbook, Wb3 As Workbook
    Dim MainBook As Workbook
    'Open All workbooks first:
    Set SourceData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SZCategoryData")
    Set TailoredData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SZCategory tailored")
    Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("D:\Userfiles\zbadah\Downloads\destination.xlsm")
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    LastRow1 = SourceData.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastRow2 = TailoredData.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = 2 To 5000
        For j = 4 To 300



            If SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "BRM_ID" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then

                     SourceData.Cells(i, 5).Cells.Copy
                     Wb1.Sheets("SZCategory tailored").Cells(j, 2).PasteSpecial

              ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "PCP TYPE" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
                    SourceData.Cells(i, 5).Cells.Copy
                    Wb1.Sheets("SZCategory tailored").Cells(j, 3).PasteSpecial

              ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "BRM REQ ID" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
                    SourceData.Cells(i, 5).Cells.Copy
                    Wb1.Sheets("SZCategory tailored").Cells(j, 4).PasteSpecial


              ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "1A WORKPACKAGE" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
                    SourceData.Cells(i, 5).Cells.Copy
                    Wb1.Sheets("SZCategory tailored").Cells(j, 6).PasteSpecial




               ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "PCP FLAG" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
                    SourceData.Cells(i, 5).Cells.Copy
                    Wb1.Sheets("SZCategory tailored").Cells(j, 13).PasteSpecial




                ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "PCP FLAG 2" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
                    SourceData.Cells(i, 5).Cells.Copy
                    Wb1.Sheets("SZCategory tailored").Cells(j, 7).PasteSpecial





             ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "UAT DROP" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
                    SourceData.Cells(i, 5).Cells.Copy
                    Wb1.Sheets("SZCategory tailored").Cells(j, 8).PasteSpecial



              ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "RELEASE" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then

                    SourceData.Cells(i, 5).Cells.Copy
                    Wb1.Sheets("SZCategory tailored").Cells(j, 9).PasteSpecial




             ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "WN TYPE" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
                    SourceData.Cells(i, 5).Cells.Copy
                     Wb1.Sheets("SZCategory tailored").Cells(j, 10).PasteSpecial



            ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "IMPACTED BY PCP" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
                    SourceData.Cells(i, 5).Cells.Copy
                    Wb1.Sheets("SZCategory tailored").Cells(j, 11).PasteSpecial


            ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "Baseline" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
                    SourceData.Cells(i, 5).Cells.Copy
                    Wb1.Sheets("SZCategory tailored").Cells(j, 12).PasteSpecial






            End If
            Next
        Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


End Sub
```

Comment: This can be anything if it is a force close without any error message. Things you can do: (1) make sure you use the latest version/bulid of Excel, if not update. (2) make sure it is not your system only that crashes, try on other computers with the exact same Excel version. (3) If it is a bug report it to Microsoft Support (4) If it works on other systems clean up your system, maybe re-install Office or even Windows. (5) If there were any error messages tell us which and where.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have not an error message. I am going to try those solution many thank !

Comment: What you can also try is save the file as `xlsb` file if it contains a large amount of data. Excel is still buggy with `xlsm/xlsx` files and large data. It also might be that you don't have enough memory, then copy smaller amounts of data or using a 64bit Office can be a solution. 32 Bit is limited to 2 GB of memory only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure if you will see a difference with the code below, but I thought I would give this a go, also I removed all the copy and paste and simply passed the values from one cell to another:

```
Sub test()
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, SourceData As Worksheet, TailoredData As Worksheet
Dim i as Long, j as Long
'Open All workbooks first:
Set SourceData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SZCategoryData")
Set TailoredData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SZCategory tailored")
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("D:\Userfiles\zbadah\Downloads\destination.xlsm")
Set ws1 = Wb1.Worksheets("SZCategory tailored")
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'LastRow1 = SourceData.Cells(SourceData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
''get the last row with data from SourceData Column A
'LastRow2 = TailoredData.Cells(TailoredData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
''get the last row with data from TailoredData Column A

For i = 2 To 5000
    For j = 4 To 300
        If SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "BRM_ID" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            ws1.Cells(j, 2) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "PCP TYPE" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            ws1.Cells(j, 3) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "BRM REQ ID" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            ws1.Cells(j, 4) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "1A WORKPACKAGE" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            ws1.Cells(j, 6) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "PCP FLAG" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            ws1.Cells(j, 13) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "PCP FLAG 2" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            ws1.Cells(j, 7) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "UAT DROP" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            ws1.Cells(j, 8) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "RELEASE" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            ws1.Cells(j, 9) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "WN TYPE" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            ws1.Cells(j, 10) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "IMPACTED BY PCP" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            ws1.Cells(j, 11) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "Baseline" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            ws1.Cells(j, 12) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

Using Select Case instead of If and ElseIF:

```
Sub test()
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, SourceData As Worksheet, TailoredData As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long
'Open All workbooks first:
Set SourceData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SZCategoryData")
Set TailoredData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SZCategory tailored")
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("D:\Userfiles\zbadah\Downloads\destination.xlsm")
Set ws1 = Wb1.Worksheets("SZCategory tailored")
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LastRow1 = SourceData.Cells(SourceData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data from SourceData Column A
LastRow2 = TailoredData.Cells(TailoredData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data from TailoredData Column A

For i = 2 To LastRow1
    For j = 4 To LastRow2
        If SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            Select Case SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value
                Case "BRM_ID"
                    ws1.Cells(j, 2) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
                Case "PCP TYPE"
                    ws1.Cells(j, 3) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
                Case "BRM REQ ID"
                    ws1.Cells(j, 4) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
                Case "1A WORKPACKAGE"
                    ws1.Cells(j, 6) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
                Case "PCP FLAG"
                    ws1.Cells(j, 13) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
                Case "PCP FLAG 2"
                    ws1.Cells(j, 7) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
                Case "UAT DROP"
                    ws1.Cells(j, 8) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
                Case "RELEASE"
                    ws1.Cells(j, 9) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
                Case "WN TYPE"
                    ws1.Cells(j, 10) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
                Case "IMPACTED BY PCP"
                    ws1.Cells(j, 11) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
                Case "Baseline"
                    ws1.Cells(j, 12) = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
            End Select
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: @Lovemaths I've updated my answer to use Select Case instead of If and ElseIF, but to be honest you are doing two nested For Loops the first from 2 to 5000 and the second from 4 to 300, so in essence you are actually doing around 1.5 million comparisons, so it will take some time....

Comment: I don't know how can I thank you ! It's very fast ! Have a nice day!

Comment: @Lovemaths, you could thank me by accepting my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks :)

Comment: Of courses it helped too much from 30 minutes to less than 2 minutes. It's just amazing! Thank you !